# Drupal forgot password

Tags: drupal-6

My application has *forgot password* option where i m sending a one time password to user via email. **(Drupal 6)**
for the mail content i m using drupal password recovery mail and sending a temporary password.

**Operations :** 
1. Generate password. (Custom)
2. Update users table.(Manual updation) 
3. *Notifying the user through email.(Drupal)*

**Question:**
The password updation in users table is happening fine(storing in MD5 format) and mail is generated to user containing password.

***Once user logs in with generated password,he succeessfully logs in and drupal updates the generated password to some new password.***

Y is this so? is it because of using the password_recovery mail content?

Comment: Your question is not really clear to me - are you asking if this is whats actually happening, or how you could do it like this? IIRC, the standard Drupal-6 'reset password' mechanism does _not_ send a newly generated password, but a one time login link, which leads the user to his profile page where he is asked to set a new password himself.

Comment: Thanks Henrik, My application requires to send the temproray  password (and update this to _users_ table) to user, for this i have altered the submit hook but, once the user logs in using temp password the _users_ table getting updated after login (So user table ll not be having generated PWD).

Answer (score 0):

There is no way, the drupal will not change the password for a successful login. Please check that whether you are not using any form_alter hook for login submit.